# What do I do in order to make my Madlibs program accessible from this log in/password program?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, window

(First post on Stack, woopee!)
I wrote a Madlibs program that takes in user input, and makes a story out of it. I also made a user log in program that I want to test using the Mad libs program. It works mostly fine, but there is one problem and I'll go through it. 
The problem starts out with the log in screen. Once I use input the proper keywords(dodo and foo), the log in screen logs in, turns itself off, and then calls up the MadLibsGUI program. But here's my problem: When I do this, for some reason the MadLibsGUI program spawns TWO windows. I have a suspicious that the problem lies in the MadLibsGUI's `main` method .  I've tried fixing it already, and it hasn't seemed to work. The program works fine, but the two windows does bother me. I'll post both code classes below for you to read and look at. Both are fairly simple (I'm a beginner programmer), so you shouldn't have that much of a problem with them. If you have any additional comments or corrections, please don't hesitate to correct them.

LogInScreen:

```
package passwordProgram;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import madLibs.MadLibsGUI;

public class LogInScreen implements ActionListener {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        LogInScreen logger = new LogInScreen();
        logger.start();
    }

    JButton logIn;
    JFrame frame;
    JTextField username;
    JPasswordField password;
    JLabel title;

    public void start() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);

        JButton logIn = new JButton("Log In");
        logIn.addActionListener(this);


        title = new JLabel("Welcome to the Username/Password System");
        JLabel usernameTxt = new JLabel("Username: ");
        username = new JTextField(15);

        JLabel passwordTxt = new JLabel("Password: ");
        password = new JPasswordField(15);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, logIn);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, title);

        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints left = new GridBagConstraints();
        left.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        GridBagConstraints right = new GridBagConstraints();
        right.weightx = (int) 2;
        right.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        right.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        panel.add(usernameTxt, left);
        panel.add(passwordTxt, right);
        panel.add(username, right);
        panel.add(passwordTxt, left);
        panel.add(password, right);

        logIn.addActionListener(this);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (username.getText().equals("dodo") && new String(password.getPassword()).equals("foo")) {
            MadLibsGUI mLibs = new MadLibsGUI();
            mLibs.start();
            frame.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            title.setText("Invalid username/password. Please try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

MadLibsGUI class:

```
package madLibs;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class MadLibsGUI implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel; 

    JTextField nameTxt;
    JTextField verbTxt1;
    JTextField adjTxt;
    JTextField verbTxt2;
    JTextField nounTxt;

    JTextArea story;

    public void start() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton madLibButton = new JButton("Lib it!");

        story = new JTextArea();

        JLabel title = new JLabel("Welcome to mad libs! \n Put in your words and press the 'Lib It' button to play!");
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
        JLabel verbLabel1 = new JLabel("Verb: ");
        JLabel adjLabel = new JLabel("Adjective: ");
        JLabel verbLabel2 = new JLabel("Verb: ");
        JLabel nounLabel = new JLabel("Noun: ");

        nameTxt = new JTextField(25);
        verbTxt1 = new JTextField(25);
        adjTxt = new JTextField(25);
        verbTxt2 = new JTextField(25);
        nounTxt = new JTextField(25);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, story);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, title);

        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.green);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        GridBagConstraints left = new GridBagConstraints();
        left.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        GridBagConstraints right = new GridBagConstraints();
        right.weighty = 1.2;
        GridBagConstraints middle = new GridBagConstraints();
        middle.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        right.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        right.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        panel.add(nameLabel, left);
        panel.add(nameTxt, right);
        panel.add(verbLabel1, left);
        panel.add(verbTxt1, right);
        panel.add(adjLabel, left);
        panel.add(adjTxt, right);
        panel.add(verbLabel2, left);
        panel.add(verbTxt2, right);
        panel.add(nounLabel, left);
        panel.add(nounTxt, right);
        panel.add(madLibButton, right);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(615, 500);

        madLibButton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String text =  ("\tThere once was a boy named " + nameTxt.getText() + " who loved to " + verbTxt1.getText()
                + ". \n\tOne day, " + nameTxt.getText() + " was walking down the street when he saw a " + 
                adjTxt.getText() + " bird who \n\twas hurt. He quietely said, \" It's okay \n\tlittle bird, I " +
                "won't hurt you!\" Instead, " + nameTxt.getText() + "\n\tdecided that he was going " +
                " to " + verbTxt2.getText() + " the bird! Sadly, the bird \n\t" + verbTxt2.getText() + "ed too" +
                " much. " + nameTxt.getText() + " was very sad. \n\tHe sat in his room, playing with his " + 
                nounTxt.getText() + ". \n\n \t\t\t|THE END|");
        story.append(text);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MadLibsGUI main = new MadLibsGUI();
        main.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the following twice in the method `start()`:

```
    logIn.addActionListener(this);
```

Which means each time the button is clicked  the `actionPerformed()` method is executed twice.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I'd upvote if I could, but I have no rep.